# Website only works completely when I cache refresh on Chrome, works fine on other browsers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, polymer

having a bit of a weird bug. This just started happening in the last 2 days with Chrome only -- the website works fine with Firefox/Opera/IE11 etc. I have no code that messes with the caching of my website to my knowledge.

I am using Google Polymer in order to load shadowDOM custom elements into my DOM. I have a script that still works fine for IE that detects whether the website is IE10 or below, and if it is, doesn't load the script, because if I load the `platform.js` in IE10 and below my website will just not load at all. Everything was working fine with the script until about 2 days ago when suddenly `platform.js` is not loading in Chrome, so none of my polymer elements are loading now UNLESS I shift+cmd+refresh my website, clearing the cache.

Was something updated with Chrome / Polymer in the last few days that would have broken this for some reason?

Has anyone encountered this kind of thing where a website will only work when you hard refresh it? I am so confused. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Polymer 0.5.*?  Because if so, you need to load webcomponents.js, not platform.js.

Comment: What about Polymer 1 ? I am facing issue but with Polymer 1. @KyleHorkley